# Deploy a server without programming knowledge

Tags: windows, joomla

Currently I have a dedicated server with WHM and Joomla running.

I want to transfer it to new server. This new server has high speed bandwidth.
I only have remote access to the new server which has Win 2008 R2 installed and it shows it was installed on a VM.

I need to configure this server to run a domain name with Joomla which will be access by 10k visitors/month.

I have knowledge on WHM and CPanel only. How I can started with any ready made packages?

The reason my management changed the server is for better performance as current dedicated server is slower.

However, I guess the new server is installed on a VM..

Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is not move your Joomla site to a Windows server. The configuration of the server is critical to the performance of Joomla and you will have nagging issues until the end of time trying to run Joomla on Windows. It can be done, but it's a massive headache and there is absolutely no advantage to doing so. There are dozens of reputable hosting companies that have servers configured specifically to run Joomla optimally. Take a look at Rochen (I have over 50 sites on Rochen) or CloudAccess, both have official relationships with the Joomla project and both have very reasonable pricing.

Also, 10k visitors per month does not require a dedicated server unless all of those users are on simultaneously running SQL query heavy apps. You could easily run a site that size on a managed virtual server and have no performance issues at all. I've got sites with hundreds of thousands of monthly visitors running on a single MVS with no issues at all.